# jQuery function with selectors as parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a function that add automatically value of the current element into another selector, something like this:

```js
function calculate(current,selector) {
    var sum = $(selector).val();
        if (!isNaN($(current).value) && $(current).value.length != 0) {
            sum += parseFloat($(current).value);
        }
    $(selector).val(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="one" onkeyup="calculate(this,'#three')" >
<input type="text" id="two" onkeyup="calculate(this,'#five')" >
<input type="text" id="three">
<input type="text" id="five">
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing to `onkeyup` already executed function, so basically you're passing `undefined` as something that will be called. Try with:

```
<input type="text" id="two" onkeyup="() => calculate(this,'#five')" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" id="one" onkeyup="calculate(this,'#three')" >
<input type="text" id="two" onkeyup="calculate(this,'#five')" >
<input type="text" id="three">
<input type="text" id="five">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    function calculate(current,selector) {
        var sum = parseFloat($(selector).val());
        var num = parseFloat($(current).val());
        if(!isNaN(num)){
            if(isNaN(sum)){
                $(selector).val(num)
            }
            else {
                $(selector).val(sum+num)
            }
        } 
    }
</script>
</html>
</body>
```

But I don't recommand you to do that. 
You see with the onkeyup you are gonna have some weird result with your sum if someone type something higher than 10

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$(current).value
```

to

```
$(current).val()
```

The code changed:

```
function calculate(current,selector) {
var sum = $(selector).val();
    if (!isNaN($(current).val()) && $(current).val().length != 0) {
        sum += parseFloat($(current).val());
    }
$(selector).val(parseFloat(sum).toFixed(3) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you were using `.value`, sometimes you used `.val()`.

Changing all of them to `.val()` made it work for me.

Plus, I suggest you to use the unary operator `+` instead of `parse…()` methods. Just because it's cooler!

Here is the snippet I ended-up with:

```js
function calculate(current, selector) {
  var sum = +$(selector).val();
  if (!isNaN($(current).val()) && $(current).val().length != 0) {
    sum += +$(current).val();
  }
  $(selector).val(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="one" onkeyup="calculate(this,'#three')">
<input type="text" id="two" onkeyup="calculate(this,'#five')">
<input type="text" id="three">
<input type="text" id="five">
```

Hope it helps.